# No output from Kalman filter in 2D object tracking

Tags: python, opencv, kalman-filter

I'm trying to apply Kalman filter with opencv in python for tracking position of a ball. I can already detect it but there is still some noise I want to eliminate. There are two variables I measure - x and y position - and there are four variables I would like to get - x and y position and x and y velocity - but I get none. When I display x0, y0, vy and vx on the screen I get "[.0]".

Another problem is that I cannot apply control matrix to kalman.predict() function because I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in gemm, file /tmp/opencv3-20170518-8732-1bjq2j7/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 1537
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kalman.py", line 128, in <module>
kalmanout = kalman.predict(kalman.controlMatrix)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20170518-8732-1bjq2j7/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:1537: error: (-215) a_size.width == len in function ge
```

This is the piece of code I'm using for Kalman filter (for control matrix application I use line kalmanout = kalman.predict(kalman.controlMatrix) at the end:

```
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import time

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=10,
    help="max buffer size")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum area size")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "blue"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (48, 62, 88)
greenUpper = (151, 238, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])
tintervals = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])
tPrev = 0;
pRad = 0
mapix = 0
mspeed = 0

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
    # keep looping

#initialize background subtraction
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    displayx = 0
    # start counting time
    tPrev = time.time()

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame and apply background subtraction
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    mask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)

    # blur the frame and convert it to the HSV
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(res, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "blue", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        pRad = radius
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # update time intervals queue
    tintervals.appendleft(time.time() - tPrev)

    # update the points queue
    pts.appendleft(center)

    # predict position of the ball
    if (pRad > 0 and len(pts) > 5):
        if pts[0] != None and pts[1] != None:
            apix = 98.1/(0.032/pRad)
            mapix = apix

            y0 = pts[0][1]
            x0 = pts[0][0]

            kalmanin = np.array((2,1), np.float32) # measurement
            kalmanout = np.zeros((4,1), np.float32) # tracked / prediction

            kalmanin = np.array([[np.float32(x0)],[np.float32(y0)]])

            tkalman = 0.01

            kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(4,2)
            kalman.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],np.float32)
            kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1,0,tkalman,0],[0,1,0,tkalman],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]],np.float32)
            kalman.controlMatrix = np.array([[0],[0.5*(tkalman**2.0)], [0],[tkalman]],np.float32) * mapix
            kalman.processNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.03
            kalman.processNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.03
            kalman.measurementNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]],np.float32) * 0.00009

            kalman.correct(kalmanin)
            kalmanout = kalman.predict(kalman.controlMatrix)

            x0 = kalmanout[0]
            y0 = kalmanout[1]
            vx = kalmanout[2]
            vy = kalmanout[3]

            displayx = x0

            listX = []
            listY = []

            for i in range(1, 11):
                t = 0.01 * i
                y = y0 + vy * t + (apix * (t ** 2)) / 2
                x = x0 + vx * t
                listX.append(int(x))
                listY.append(int(y))
                mspeed = vy

            for i in range(0, 9):
                cv2.line(frame, (listX[i], listY[i]), (listX[i+1], listY[i+1]), (255, 0, 0), 4)


    # loop over the set of tracked points
    for i in xrange(1, len(pts)):
        # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
        # them
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
        # draw the connecting lines
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)


    cv2.putText(frame, "y axis speed: {}".format(displayx),
        (120, frame.shape[0] - 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)


    cv2.putText(frame, "radius in px: {}".format(pRad),
        (120, frame.shape[0] - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.putText(frame, "apix: {}".format(mapix),
        (120, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    if (mapix != 0):
        cv2.putText(frame, "radius in meters: {}".format((9.81*pRad)/mapix),
            (120, frame.shape[0] - 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # shows x, y position, (newest input from pts)
    cv2.putText(frame, "x, y: {}".format(pts[0]),
        (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would move the initialization of the Kalman filter outside the loop. The main issue with your code is that you have set the control matrix. If I understand your task you are only observing the system, not controlling it. Just skip the `kalman.controlMatrix` initialization or set it to a zero matrix. In the loop you then just use

```
kalmanout = kalman.predict()
kalman.correct(kalmanin)
```

Comment: Actually, I need to predict the trajectory. Moving Kalman initialization outside the loop solves both problems, now I just need to adjust covariance. Thank you!